# Video.JS and streaming how init timeline?

Tags: video.js

I have a stream that works in video.JS. Since this is a stream, "Live" appears instead of the timeline. Can I somehow forcefully enable the timeline(seekbar) by setting the maximum duration of the broadcast?

Answer (score 0):

[videojs-dvrseekbar](https://github.com/toolbox-tve/videojs-dvrseekbar) plugin allows to force show a seekbar.